# Regional IP Address Filter is not working in Sandbox environment

Tags: authorize.net

I have enabled " Regional IP Address " filter  for some countries in Asia and set action to decline the transaction in sandbox environment but this filter is not triggered even though I am passing customer IP address in  "x_customer_ip " parameter using AIM transaction.

Please kindly assist.

Thanks

Amol

Comment: Please verify that AFDS is enabled.